# Binomial sum for an arbitrary function

Tags: functions, summation, binomial-coefficients, integral-transforms

I'm looking for some known results for sum of this type but I can't find anything.
The sum is defined as:
$$S(x,a,b,n)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{k} f((a(n-k)+bk)x)$$
where $f$ is an arbitrary function and $a$ and $b$ are real and positive constants.
For example for the function $f(x)=e^{x}$ the sum can be evaluated with Binomial Theorem and we have:
$$S(x,a,b,n)=(e^{ax}-e^{bx})^{n}$$
But for arbitrary function $f$?
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect there is no compact representation of the sum without knowledge of $f$.

Comment: There probably isn't a single method for evaluating the sum that works for all functions. If you happen to know a little bit about $f$, you can make certain generalizations, though. For example, if $f$ is linear, then $f((a(n-k)+bk)x)=f(anx)-f(akx)+f(bkx)$.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes, for an arbitrary function isn't improbable to obtain a closed form. I tried to obtain an Integral representation of the sum via Integral Transform but with no great results.